# To prove that a Brownian motion is a martingale

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales

Given $Z(t) = [w(t)]^2 -t $. I need to show that this is a martingale.

I need to show that $\mathbb{E}(z_t|f(s)]=z(s)$.

I start by:

$\mathbb{E}(z_t|f(s)] = \mathbb{E}[(w(t))^2 - (w(s))^2 + (w(s))^2 -t |f(s)]$

$= \mathbb{E}[(w(t))^2-(w(s))^2|f(s)].[(w(s)^2-t] $

Then I am stuck. I don't know how to go further.

Comment: Try to use $$W_t^2 = ((W_t-W_s)+W_s)^2$$ and the independence of the increments.

Comment: Done, and working. Thnx